# Error with One-To-Many in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am pretty new to Entity Framework and got the following problem:

```
public class Bank{
      //Showed only problem moments
      public Guid Id {get;set;}
      public List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
      public Bank(){
            Branches = new List<Branch>();  
      }      
}

public class Branch{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

I tryed to add new Bank and Branch manually from code and it worked. It also created tables in MSSQL with all PK and FKs.
However, when I tryed to do following :

```
var bankData = new ApplicationContext().Banks;
return Json(bankData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

I got only my Bank data and Branches were null.

Did I mistaked in creating the relations in CodeFirst?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of EF 4.1 and later, there is a [strongly typed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) .Include which allows the required depth of eager loading to be specified by providing Select expressions to the appropriate depth.

```
using System.Data.Entity; // NB!

var bankData = new ApplicationContext().Banks
                     .Include(b=> b.Branch)
```

or if you don't want to use `System.Data.Entity` then use

```
new ApplicationContext().Banks.Include("Branches");
```

and then return `JSON` using the same code

```
return Json(bankData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

**Eager Loading:**

Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is achieved using the Include() method.

In the following example, it gets all the students from the database along with it's standards using `Include()` method.

**Lazy Loading:**

One of the important functions of Entity Framework is lazy loading. Lazy loading means delaying the loading of related data, until you specifically request for it.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework, by default, will not populate child objects on an entity.  There are however, mechanisms for doing so.  One is to use lazy loading (which I don't like because it uses multiple database calls and can cause performance issues if the developer is not aware of what is going on), and using includes (which fetch all data in a single call).

To use an include, you could:

```
new ApplicationContext().Banks.Include("Branches");
```

Comment: oh, my deep thanks. However, only in academic purposes, could you add lazy-loading option too?

Comment: There is a lot of information available on loading related entities here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx